# php session does not destroy on refresh

Tags: php

i am making a 10 question survey with one question at a point. i made a session for passing values between questions. the thing i discovered is that the session values do not get destroyed even on a page refresh. is there a workaround or am i doing something wrong.

just to make things clear, here is the code:

```
session_start(); 
//  $_SESSION['score'] = $score;
    $_SESSION['qnum'] = isset($_SESSION['qnum']) ? $_SESSION['qnum']+1 : 1;

    if ($_SESSION['qnum'] < 10){
        $_SESSION['total'] = isset($_SESSION['total']) ? $_SESSION['total']+$score : $score;
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['qnum'] == 10){
        $_SESSION['total'] = isset($_SESSION['total']) ? $_SESSION['total']+$score : $score;
        echo "finished";
    }

    echo $_SESSION['qnum'];
    echo '\n';
    echo $_SESSION['total'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$_SESSION variables will remain until you terminate the session or unset() the session variable.

To end a session try this code:

```
$_SESSION = array();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

To delete a session variable use:

```
unset($_SESSION['variablename']);
```

Comment: And $_SESSION variables are build to survive the page refresh be design. Hard to keep the user logged into otherwise.

Comment: wrt the code above, how do you suggest to destroy the session? i mean if i destroy the session just after the code above, wont it make passing calls difficult?

Comment: If you destroy the whole session it will defeat the purpose of the session which is to track data across pages a.k.a. for a session. You probably just need to delete individual session variables when they are no longer required.

Answer (score 2):

That's the whole point of sessions - they stick around for the browsing session. You're using them like run-of-the-mill variables, which causes me to ask: why not just use normal variables?

Answer (score 0):

This is whole beauty and concept of session varible  that it will not destroy untill or unless you destroy or unset it.
What the problem , your code is completely correct , You are saving question number and total score as a session variable and score as a local .just do one thing at the end of Quiz destroy the session using sesion_destroy()

Answer (score 0):

Hidden variables may be a better tool to use for your purpose. Session variables by nature are built to last the whole application *session*.